# Going from Android to iOS in PhoneGap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, porting

How does PhoneGap work? (I'm still going through all their faqs, etc.) I downloaded the andriod sdk and installed PhoneGap stuff and also got the Hello World working on the Android emulator. Now how do I port that to actually test in say on an iPhone?

Answer (score 3):

Using PhoneGap you done all your work using only HTML/CSS/JavaScript. PhoneGap has different builds for different architectures and your project is just WebView for architecture you want to. Simply if you need to port your PhoneGap app for iOS you need to download project template for XCode and move all your HTML/CSS/JS code into the project. Just remember that portability of PhoneGap is just because of WebView and solid JS interfaces for different phones. You actually does not need to know what lies under PhoneGap just use WWW technologies.

Comment: One additional bit. When moving your assets from Android to iOS do not included the cordova.js file as it is platform dependent.

Comment: So I still need to create the iOS project in XXCode before I can deploy it to my iOS device? I thought you build it using PhoneGap and the builld does the work for you?

Comment: Yes. Just download templates for XCode and create Cordova project. Then move your WWW's assets and sources and deploy on the device.